# How do I deploy Django to a suburl using mod wsgi?

Tags: django, apache, django-templates

All of my URLs in Django are coded relative to the root URL: /login/, /logout etc. I want to deploy the app to the sub url : www.example.com/app, and I want the URLs to be www.example.com/app/login/, www.example.com/app/logout. How do I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must modify your hard coded links to use Django's reversal methods. For example, instead of

```
<a href="/login/">Login</a>
```

you should use

```
<a href="{% url 'accounts_login' %}">Login</a>
```

this will allow Django to dynamically determine the URLs with respect to the root URL.

Comment: Can you please provide more information? I defined url as     url(r'^$', interface_page, name = 'index'), and call them from template but it's not working yet. My urls are: /login, /logout, /profile/, /profile/change, and /profile/delete.

Comment: You must use the `name` of your URLs, like `{% url 'index' %}` when constructing your links in the templates. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls for details.